# Object becomes a string after accessing it

Tags: reactjs, string, object

Backend sends to frontend an Object. Object looks like this:
{body: "Items":[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}

typeof(obj) returns Object.

When I access "body", typeof(obj["body"]) returns a string and I am unable to retrieve the arrays in the "Items".

```
console.log(typeof(this.state.message)); // object
const obj = this.state.message;
console.log(obj["body"]); // string
```

My end goal is to access the data inside "Items" and convert it to a table in render(). Why does my object convert to a string?

Here's the backend code from Lambda:

```
async function listItems(){
  try {
    const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise()
    return data
  } catch (err) {
    return err
  }
}

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  try {
    const data = await listItems()
    return { body: JSON.stringify(data) }
  } catch (err) {
    return { error: err }
  }
}
```

Here's the frontend Fetch code in ReactJS:

```
async getData() {
        //this.setState({message: "test"})
        await axios.get("https://...")
        .then((response) => {
            console.log((response)); 
            console.log(typeof(response)); // object
            this.setState({message: response?.data ?? ''});
        })
    }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, your backend sends an invalid JSON. Paste your JSON into https://jsonlint.com/ and see for yourself.

Comment: Looks like you may have added the wrong object here or maybe the backend is sending the wrong one. 

Also, can you please add the fetch call or the API call to the question?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comments. I have included the backend and frontend code too. Thank you!

Comment: I've also checked, my backend code returns a valid JSON. Went into AWS to test and the result is a valid JSON.

Comment: Well,  `{body: "Items":[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}` is by no means a valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `body` property is a JSON string, so you'll need to parse it:

```
const items = JSON.parse(obj.body);
```

Then you can map over the `items` variable.

Comment: I tried to do so but I get this error instead: Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development. See https://reactjs.org/link/crossorigin-error for more information.

Comment: Read the response and fix the CORS issue. That's a separate issue from this question though.

Comment: I parsed it before sending it via state. So managed to get the answer, thanks loads!

Answer (score 0):

```
{body: "Items":[{"key1":"value","key2":"value"},{"key1":"value","key2":"value"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}
```

This JSON file seems invalid.